# What is the default terminal (shell) for Xubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, shell, xubuntu

What is the default terminal (shell) for [Xubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xubuntu)?  Does Xubuntu use the same shell as Ubuntu?

Comment: "Terminal" and "shell" are two different things.

Answer (score 7):

All Ubuntu variants use [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) as their default shell. They all use different terminal emulators. However, Xubuntu uses the [Xfce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xfce) 4 terminal emulator ([Kubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubuntu) uses konsole and Ubuntu gnome-terminal).

Answer (score 4):

You can always use "echo $SHELL" to get current shell environment.

Answer (score 3):

It's called Terminal, but it's different from the Gnome Terminal.

See [What is Terminal - Xfce](http://www.xfce.org/projects/terminal)

Comment: Specifically, in Xubuntu, this is `/usr/bin/xfce4-terminal`.